# How do I Parse Code block using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Use case:

I have a function that receives a string and I want to parse the `<Code> .... </Code>` and get the contents in between the code block.

```
const input = `<Code> Error in Something </Code>`
const getErrorMessage = parseCode(input); // Error in something
```

I'm confused on how to proceed. I initially thought of proceeding with RegEx but wasn't sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: Depends on what can *actually* be in `input`. If it's *just* bracketed by `<Code>...</Code>` then it's pretty trivial.

Comment: If the tags are always at the beginning and end, you can just use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) (or `substring`, but `slice` is probably easier for finding the end index).

Comment: Yes it's just bracketed by `<Code> Error in Header </Code>` @DaveNewton

Comment: let input = "<Code> Error in Something </Code>";
    let item1 = (input.split("<Code>")[1]).split("</Code>")[0];
item1 = stuff between two tags.

Comment: or easier: `let output = "<Code> Error in Something </Code>".replace(/<\/?Code>/, '').trim(); console.log(output);`

Comment: @RandyCasburn but this is producing this output `Error in Something </Code>` so the code close tag is still present. I am new to this and would appreciate your response.

Comment: Of course - because I forgot he greedy flag: `/<\/?Code>/g` sorry about that